# How to do selected one hot encoding on pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Here's my dataset

```
+-------+-------+
|     id|apps_id|
+-------+-------+
|7445640|    146|
|5592981|    929|
|5103715|    929|
| 386222|    114|
|7674331|    146|
+-------+-------+
```

Here's what I want

I have list like this (editable)

```
list_selected_apps_id = ['146', '929']
```

And have output like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|     id|    146|    929|
+-------+-------+-------+
|7445640|      1|      0|
|5592981|      0|      1|
|5103715|      0|      1|
| 386222|      0|      0|
|7674331|      1|      0|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` function.

```
df = df.groupBy('id', 'apps_id').pivot('apps_id').count().select('id', *list_selected_apps_id).fillna(0)
df.show(truncate=False)

# +-------+---+---+
# |id     |146|929|
# +-------+---+---+
# |7445640|1  |0  |
# |7674331|1  |0  |
# |5592981|0  |1  |
# |5103715|0  |1  |
# |386222 |0  |0  |
# +-------+---+---+
```