# How to do one hot encoding in Pandas and Pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
   id  country    amount    city  
    1  France       4         Paris
    2  Italy        9         Naples
```

I want to convert it to

```
   id amount    city    France   Italy  
    1  4        Paris     1        0
    2  9        Naples    0        1
```

How can I achieve this using Pandas and Pyspark respectively?

Comment: for pandas, there are already many resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python

Comment: see [How to do selected one hot encoding on pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72891394/8279585)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Comment: How about Pyspark?

Comment: in pyspark example, you have to explicitly name the column values. Can I use all the column value in default?

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you can use `pd.get_dummies()`.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['country'])
```